# Calculate Variable value with the help of get and set Method

Tags: c#, class, properties

I am geting data with the help of get and set methods. I want to calculate `waste` value. This is how I have tried to solve this issue.

```
class OSSP
{
    private decimal waste;

    public int DocNum { get; set; }
    public string U_ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string U_ItemName { get; set; }
    public string U_ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public string U_WetProcess { get; set; }
    public string U_Color { get; set; }
    public string U_Size { get; set; }

    public decimal U_knitgWeight { get; set; }
    public decimal U_FinishWeight { get; set; }

    OSSP ossp ;
    public decimal Waste
    {
        get => waste;
        set
        {
            waste = ossp.U_knitgWeight - ossp.U_FinishWeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put the code from the setter into the getter and remove the setter

Comment: @MongZhu 
public decimal Waste
        {
            get => waste= ossp.U_knitgWeight - ossp.U_FinishWeight;
                
        }
error occur "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: you don't need the `private decimal waste` field anymore. You only need to return the result of the calculation. Can you explain to me why you made the `OSSP ossp;` variable and use it for the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you want `Waste` to be calculated from values of other properties and you want to have this value when you try to access this property you need to put the calculation code into the getter.

```
public decimal Waste
{
    get => this.U_knitgWeight - this.U_FinishWeight;
}
```

furthermore it doesn't make sense to allow this value to be set, because it's meaning is based on the calculation of an internal state that is not visible outside. So that means that you can remove the setter entirely. By doing so you can also remove the `private decimal waste;` field because it is superfluous now.

EDIT:

One more thing that I notice is that you have an internal `OSSP ossp;` field, which is never set anywhere in your code. I assume you want to calculate with the actual values of the current object. So in this case you need to use `this.` before the 2 properties which you use for calculation.

Correct me if I am wrong here, because you might have purpose as why you made this `OSSP ossp;` field

Answer (score 0):

```
    get
    {
        return ossp.U_knitgWeight - ossp.U_FinishWeight;
    }
```

When get method gets called it returns value after calculating.

Comment: Just without posting a code add a description so that others will understand why this works.

Comment: Done adding comment